# Powershell select string or regex

Tags: powershell

I am looking how to powershell a hostname $env:COMPUTERNAME and take the hostname and grab everything in between numbers into a var. For example, let's say the hostname is abcd1efghij12kl. How do return just efghij?  The number of letters before the first number varies and the number of letters after the second number can vary.  Also to first number could be 1 or 2 digits and same for the second set of numbers.  I am looking to get only the letters in between.  Thanks

Comment: For that specific example you could -split on digits \d and take the string in the 2nd position (index 1) ('abcd1efghij12kl' -split "\d+")[1] returns efghij. Another way is to use -match and regex, 'abcd1efghij12kl' -replace ".+\d(\D+)\d.*", '$1'

Comment: That looks like it does what i want, thanks